# Sparse Pattern Recognition Using Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: time-series, classification, conv-neural-network, convolution, sparse

**Context of Problem** I am trying to troubleshoot communication issues between process sensors of a large manufacturing company. I have been given 1-year worth of data for 1,000 distinct processes (observations), as well as signals coming out of sensors at each plant.The company uses 10,000 different sensors across different plants (which are my features), however since only a subset is used at any given plant, the matrices are immensely sparse. Aside from sparsity and imbalanced issue (only 5% of the processes (observations) experience alarms), **the main challenge is that we do not know if the alarms were caused by single-day communication issues or issues that accumulated over time and surpassed thresholds, and therefore information loss is very critical.**

Now I have transformed the time-series into feature matrices (heat-maps) where the x-axis corresponds to time, and the y-axis are the 10,000 sensors/ features. I am trying to classify the sparse images, like the one shown below using a convolutional neural network, however the sparsity results in loss of data as I perform convolution.

So my questions are:

**1) Whats the best method to deal with sparsity in convolutional networks (to avoid information loss as much as possible)?**

**2)Are there additional methods that can assist with this classification problem, given that the duration of event of interest is not known?**
[image]

Comment: Let me ask a couple of questions first. How many images like this do you have? Does it correspond to the number of plants? Yoy speak about a classification problem. How are your classes defined? What is the x-size of your image? Is it one year?

Comment: There are about 1000 distinct processes (Images) which does correspond to number of plants. There are two distinct classes, one being plants that experienced alarms while the other class did not. Each pixel on the x axis corresponds to a day (which stretches for 5 years) while each row/pixels on the y-axis corresponds to a specific control unit.

Comment: Have you ordered the y rows in a way that their y-location corresponds to some similarity? CNNs are designed to exploit spatial correlation/patterns in the data, but from your description it doesn't seem like you should expect any spatial patterns along the y-axis. I'm skeptical that CNNs are going to be the right tool here, precisely because they rely on downsampling/convolving the image to get at more basic spatial patterns.

Comment: Very good perspective, no the spatial placement on the y-axis are arbitrary., but constant throughout all images. I was hoping that since they remain the same throughout the 1,100 images, the network can perhaps distinguish the relevant patterns. Do you have any suggestions on a better approach?